# MS Outlook won't to preview attachments with specific file extensions

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, office365, attachments, preview

On one PC I can't handle with opening previews of some files from attachment in Outlook 365.
This issue is only with one PC. Previews on another PCs are working well. All PCs are in same domain with same policies.
For now I have found this issue only with files with extensions JPG and XML.
Another extensions like PNG, BMP or DOCX, XLSX, PDF even LOG, TXT are working well.

**Any idea how to fix it?**

---

## **Detailed problem description:**

---

Software:

> Windows 10 Enterprise (21H2) 64-bit
> Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13127.21656) 32-bit
> IrfanView 4.54 64-bit

---

**Screenshots:**

**[Screenshot 1: Issue with Outlook - Error messages and temporary files folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZkDZ.png)**

**Screenshot 1 description:**

Warning message instead of file preview:

> "This file cannot be previewed. Try opening the file in the program in which it was created"

- This message above has appeared after first one-click on attached file.
- After first one-click the preview is not visible but JPG file is immediately downloaded to Outlook temporary folder.

Error message after double click on file:

> Attachment Security Warning
> Warning!
> This file may contain a virus that can be harmufl to your computer. ...

- And second error message window has appeared after double click on attached file.

**[Screenshot 2: Well working Outlook - previewed attechment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cdEG.png)**

**Screenshot 2 description:**

- Preview of attachments appears immediately after first one-click on it.
- After double click on BMP or PNG will appear a prompt window with three options (Open, Save, Cancel).

---

**What I've tried - my failed solutions:**

I found some possible solutions on similar issues like I have. But nothing helped on my specific issue.

At example:

- [Possible solution 1: Office-Trust Center - Uncheck all options in Protected View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efYEM.png)

> I unchecked them but without effect. Of course, I quit Word and Outlook and after then I tested previews in Outlook.

- [Possible solution 2: Delete content of temporary folder for Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gXcA.png)

> Location for Temporary files folder:
> C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook

- [Possible solution 3: In the Windows change a default Photo viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I9bT.png)

> I set IrfanView and Windows Photo Viewer between each other but without any effect.

- [Possible solution 4: Outlook-Trust Center - turn on desired previewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N4jq.png)

> I didn't find any image or XML previewer here.

- [Possible solution 5 - Via dcomcnfg (Win+R) check if it is set Default Auth.Level: Connect & Default Imper. Level: Identify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UmSI.png)

> It was set right.

- Possible solution 6 - Uninstallation of IrfanView 64bit & Installation of IrfanView 32bit

> At first I unninstalled IrfanView 64-bit, then I was set Windows photo viewer as default app for JPG, then I started Outlook but it didn't help.
> As second I installed IrfanView 32-bit but it didn't help either.

- based on @Faery 's [Possible solution 7 - start Outlook in safe mode and disabling all Add-ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3tWv.png)

> Like @Faery described in his comment. I started Outlook in safe mode in which the previews worked. So I disabled all Add-ins except one which was not possible to disable. But after start Outlook in normal mode the previews didn't work.

---

Comment: I am not sure - I get Outlook Previews here. Two things:  (a) the attachment may be incompatible.  (b) consider trying Office 64-bit so it works well with IfranView 64-bit (which I also have).

Comment: @John  

(a) on another PCs the same attachments working for preview so attachment must be OK.   

(b) It's similar case as I mention in previous point. On another PCs are 32bit Office and they are working good. Unfortunately it's not on me which version of Office is installed on PCs. I can't install on 64bit Office.

Comment: @Mike_BossO - If possible, please run a [ProcMon trace](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/process-monitor-track-events-generate-log-file/) on the subject computer (that has the issue) and upload the log (zipped) to your OneDrive. It lets us see what's happening under the hood when clicking on the JPG attachment.

Comment: @w32sh - I would like to send record from ProcMon but it contains sensitive data which I don't want to publish. But thanks to you and ProcMon I found solution. I will post it on bottom.

Comment: @Mike_BossO: Glad to hear the issue is sorted out with the help of P'Mon. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in my registry

> Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security\
> String value: Level1Remove
> Value data: .xml;.jpg

I'm pretty sure that this was a remain after my past debugging of similar problem with XML file attachment. Unfortunately I forget to delete that string and didn't notice that JPGs stopped working.
[Screenshot of Registry Editor & Outlook XML attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Hiq.png)

**Thank you with your assistance with resolving of issue which I created by myself :)**

Comment: Excellent. Additional information on this subject is here → [Unblock Attachments - HowTo-Outlook](https://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/blockedattachments.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try Working in Outlook safe and check if it helps. To know how to start Outlook in Safe mode, follow the steps below.

Go to Start >Search box and type outlook /safe, then press Enter.
If Outlook safe works as expected, disable the add-ins as suggested below:

a. Click on File menu.

b. Click Options.

c. Click Add-ins.

d. Click on Go button besides Manage: Com-Add-in.

e. Check if there are add-ins listed, clear the checkbox to disable them.

f. Close the Outlook and restart it.

Comment: In safe mode the preview is working well. So I disabled Add-ins as you described, then I restarted Outlook to normal mode but it didn't help.
On of the Add-ins was not possible to disable.